# Switching between the Midlets

Tags: java-me, midp

I want to know how to switch between two Midlets i.e. Go from First Midlet to Second Midlet on pressing command?

Comment: i have tried create a instance of second midlet in first and call the startapp()

Comment: _creating an instance_ should throw SecurityException [per API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#MIDlet()), didn't you know that? Also the way you describe it I wonder why do you think you need second midlet at all? Is there anything you can't do by using plain java object/thread?

Comment: I am doing all for learing Purpose ya it threw an exception i have just started j2me

Answer (score 0):

MIDP 1.0 specified only one way to start a MIDlet: manual activation by the user.The MIDP 2.0 specification adds two new mechanisms to launch a MIDlet: in response to an incoming connection or at a scheduled time. The new javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry class handles both.
You can use Alarms to Launch MIDlets.The PushRegistry.registerAlarm() method Registers a timer-based alarm to launch the Midlet.It supports one outstanding wake up time per MIDlet **in the current suite**.(So target midlet must be registered in the JAD or manifest file)

In the MIDlet source code include:

```
...

import  javax.microedtion.io.PushRegistry;
```

and in your commandAction method:

```
...
String  MIDletname = "yourMIDletName";
Date date = new Date();
long currentTime = date.getTime();
long nextTime = currentTime  + 2000;
PushRegistry.registerAlarm( MIDletname, nextTime );
...
```

References:
[How can a MIDlet be launched automatically?](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/pushregistry/)
[The MIDP 2.0 Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/)